# Upsert not generating an ID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So I've seen that many have had this issue, but all of them seem to be for an older driver version and the solutions aren't working for me. Basicaly, when I run `ReplaceOneAsync(...)` with a new object (no Id), it gets inserted, but with no ID. The most popular answer was to add `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` to the Id attribute of the document so that the serializer didn't think it was set, which is not working for me. Here's the base class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(Inherited = true)]
public abstract class MongoEntity : IMongoEntity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the upsert method:

```
public async Task<T> UpsertAsync(T entity)
{
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, entity.Id);
    await _collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
        filter,
        entity,
        new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

    return entity;
}
```

Any ideas?

MongoDB.Driver version 2.4.1.18

Comment: I've observed the same behavior.  I have an id generator so I called IsEmpty() and do an insert instead.  Mongo also makes it annoyingly difficult to log bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Old issue I know, but for anyone still running into this problem:

[Per the official issue here,](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1805) **if your filter includes Id as a parameter**, then when the filter finds no docs the id is set to 00000000000, and using [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] does nothing to prevent this, apparently by design.

This means that if you want an update function to find a document by _id and insert it if it doesn't exist, well, too bad.

Luckily for my use case there will never be documents that are identical except for their ids, so I was able to filter by other values on the documents (this still requires the [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] attribute), but this is obviously less than ideal.

Hope this helps.